# Reading a file in Rails Template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, templates

I'm making a Rails template file as introduced below:

- http://asciicasts.com/episodes/148-app-templates-in-rails-2-3

I have a big file I want to make, so instead of doing:

```
file "bigfile.txt", <<-EOF
  content of the file...
EOF
```

I want to read the content from another file. What I have now is:

```
file "public/stylesheets/sass/960.sass", File.read(File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "960.sass")))
```

The file is located in the same directory as the rails template file. The problem is: when I try to make a rails app with the template (i.e., `rails new_app -m rails_template/rails_template.rb`, I get the following error:

```
The template [rails_template/rails_template.rb] could not be loaded. Error: (eval):129:in `read': No such file or directory - /Users/myusername/Desktop/new_app/960.sass
```

This is all because `__SELF__` is not working the way I expected. I expect `__SELF__` to be the template file itself, but in reality, `__SELF__` is poiting to the root of the app or somewhere else.

Is there a way to load file in a rails template?

Comment: Looking at the article I can't see anything close to this, what are you actually trying to achieve here? Loading in a stylesheet from a separate file? Why do you need to load the stylesheet at all? Can it not be passed straight to the browser?

Comment: I'm making my own custom rails template. I'm trying to load a SASS file into a new app which is generated with the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem reading a file from within a template. If you were to hard code the path to the source copy of 960.sass then it would work fine.

As you suspect the problem lies with the use of `__FILE__`. The reason is that if you look in **rails-2.3.4\lib\rails_generator\generators\applications\app\template_runner.rb** you will see that `load_template` loads the template into a string and then executes it using `instance_eval`:

```
def load_template(template)
  begin
    code = open(template).read
    in_root { self.instance_eval(code) }
  rescue LoadError, Errno::ENOENT => e
    raise "The template [#{template}] could not be loaded. Error: #{e}"
    end
end
```

Hence when your code executes the context is an eval block and `__FILE__` won't point to your file.

The good news is that the `template` parameter passed to `load_template` (containing the path to your template) is a local variable at the point when `instance_eval` is called and so is available from the code inside your template. If instead you just do:

```
File.dirname(template)
```

then it should work. Be aware though that you are then tying your code to the current implementation of `load_template`, which could change in the future.